# Irrigation Ball Valve Replacement

Tags: plumbing, irrigation

The 3/4" ball valve coming out of the house has cracked and is leaking. Is the only way to replace is to cut the pipe below the valve and then on the other down pipe going into the cement? I haven't sweat copper in a very long time and was hoping to avoid it. I didn't know if there was another method to unscrew the valve that I am missing or are there outdoor rated compression couplings that can be used instead? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Don’t cut it, un-sweat it.  Are you in a freezing climate?  I assume that’s how the valve cracked?  That needs to be turned off inside and blown out, or you’ll be doing this every years or so, that valves not meant to be winter shutoff.

Comment: Yeah, we live in Denver. It was blown out, but we had an early freeze where it dropped below 30 one night before they were blown out. Not sure if that was enough to have done it though. I have never repaired pipe before, just installed along time ago. Which joints would be my best bet to un-sweat and can I just clean out the old solder to reattach everything or is it best to replace the couplings? Thanks

Comment: I’m not certain that was blown out correctly, it would take a hard freeze, not one night of 30.  If you don’t want to sweat it, cut the left side in the middle and the right side as high as possible under the valve (you need to leave as much pipe above the elbow as possible.  Then use Sharkbite fittings to reattach.. you will need to clean and sand the exterior of the pipe back to smooth.

Comment: I didn't know if Sharkbite was suitable for outdoors or not. Would sweating be a safer option? What would be my best bet if I went that route so I can weigh by options? Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Cutting or not, you will have to sweat something at some point. I would do it just by sweating all around, it's actually more work to cut something and then have to repair it.

Comment: Put in a union when you rebuild it. Also, a professional plumber may be required to replace your anti-siphon valve if he does any repair. Most localities require an expensive spring actuated anti-siphon valve on any retrofit today.

Comment: Unions are a great idea, especially for the DIY crowd because it allows for a simple way top re-make the connections.